How to update `deno.lock` on removing a dependency?
When I add a dependency in my code, the deno.lock file gets updated and I see that the package's URL is visible in deno.lock.
Now when I remove the import from my code and run deno cache --reload <file.ts>, the previous URL is still visible.
Ideally I'd want the state to be such that I never installed that package.

In the Deno manual, the section Integrity Checking & Lock Files explains the purpose of a lockfile. You can delete your lockfile and recreate it if you'd like to curate the history.

^ If this answers your question, I can write it as one — if not, what am I missing?

@jsejcksn i don't think it makes sense to delete the lockfile completely. i'm just looking for a way to remove data related to a specific package from the lockfile while keeping the rest intact.

^ If you’re asking how to manually modify a lockfile (JSON data), please [edit] the question to include a [mre] and be sure to include the desired output. There is no mode in Deno to overwrite a lockfile — it is an additive operation by design.

In the newest Deno versions, this should happen by default whenever deno executes/caches your dependencies again. (unless lock.frozen is true in your deno.json)
For version >= 1.45,
deno --frozen=false cache -A main.ts

For versions < 1.45,
deno --lock-write=true cache -A main.ts

